# Set Batch off just for a group of requests

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

i have a question is there a way to set for consecutive request the batchmodus off? i can set it on the modelbase but than it is deactivated overall -> thats not what i want, just for these example of requests. Why? because we have lagacy code in the backend and there is a commit, commit and batch does not like each other o.o

e.g. => thats just a coded example.

```
    oData.forEach(element => {
            if (element.isSelected) {
                if (!bValidationError) {
                    oTCGW.create("/TestSet('" + element.test + "')/L", L, {
                        useBatch: false,
                        success: function (oData) {
                            oTCGW.create("/TestSet2('" + element.no + "')/C", C, {
                                useBatch: false,
                                success: function (oData2) {
                                    oTCGW.callFunction("/TestFunc", {
                                        useBatch: false,
                                        method: "POST",
                                        urlParameters: {
                                            no: element.no,
                                            name: name,
                                            plate: plate
                                        },
                                        success: function (osuccess) {
                                            that.oParentController._readDataFromBackendFull();
                                            that.onPressExit();

                                        },
                                        error: function (oerror) {

                                        }

                                    });
                                },
                                error: function (odata2) {

                                }

                            });
                        },
                        error: function (oData) {

                            }
                    });
```

Comment: Is using promises and async/await an option? You would have to make your code more readable and then you could deactivate batch before your calls and when they are done you could activate it again.

Comment: Oh Jesus.. yeah you right .. I can set it just back on.. sometimes you don’t see the most easiest way  thanks.